# how to recover a bad json in python

Tags: python, json, database

In this moment, i have to work on a database with a bad json.
So when i try to recover all line 1 per 1 in python, it's impossible, because the database has always a problem

[image: picture of some line of database]

I have no idea how to recover it  to work on this database.

I tried this :

```
my_json = {

"name": "Khau0304lid Muhu0323ammad u02bbAliu0304 al-Hu0323au0304jj",
"personal_name": "Khau0304lid Muhu0323ammad u02bbAliu0304 al-Hu0323au0304jj",
"last_modified": {
    "type": "/type/datetime",
    "value": "2008-08-20T17:57:09.66187"
},
"key": "/authors/OL1000057A",
"type": {
    "key": "/type/author"
},
"revision": 2
```

}

```
name = my_json.get('name', "")
print(name)
```

But when Ihave more than 1 name,  it doesn't work

Thanks for your attention !

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .Do not use images or screenshots of code. Please provide an example of json that is bad. Let it be as small as possible while still reproducing the problem

Answer (score 2):

OK,Here is a example to slice many json string.

```
my_json = '{"name": "Khau0304lid Muhu0323ammad u02bbAliu0304 al-Hu0323au0304jj",\
"personal_name": "Jacques", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value":\
"2008-08-20T17:57:09.66187"}, "key": "/authors/OL1000057A", "type": {"key":\
"/type/author"}, "revision": 2},{"name": "sdsdsdzzdzdfdfe", "personal_name":\
"Khau0304lid Muhu0323ammad u02bbAliu0304 al-Hu0323au0304jj", "last_modified": {"type":\
"/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T17:57:09.66187"}, "key": "/authors/OL1000057A",\
"type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}'
JsonList = []
Stack = []
LastJsonEndIndex = 0
PassADot = False
for i in range(len(my_json)):
    if PassADot:
        PassADot = False
        continue
    if my_json[i] == "{":
        Stack.append(my_json[i])
    elif my_json[i] == "}":
        Stack.pop()
        if Stack == []:
            JsonList.append(my_json[LastJsonEndIndex:i+1])
            LastJsonEndIndex = i+2
            PassADot = True
    else:
        pass
print(JsonList)
```

Every element in `JsonList` is a complete json string.You can save every element of `JsonList` to a json file,And run what I post firstly.

Save it:

```
my_json = '{"name": "Nazamiu0304 Rau0304majiu0304", "personal_name": "Nazamiu0304 Rau0304majiu0304", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T18:00:41.270799"}, "key": "/authors/OL1001461A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2} {"name": "Harald A. Enge", "personal_name": "Harald A. Enge", "created": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "alternate_names": ["Harald A Enge"], "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2013-02-25T09:47:06.574533"}, "latest_revision": 3, "key": "/authors/OL1001542A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 3} {"name": "Umu Hilmy", "personal_name": "Umu Hilmy", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-09-08T16:20:28.105165"}, "key": "/authors/OL100223A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2} {"name": "Ismail Ibrahim Dr.", "title": "Dr.", "personal_name": "Ismail Ibrahim", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "key": "/authors/OL100304A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 1} {"bio": {"type": "/type/text", "value": "> "Eversley, William Pinder, B.C.L. Queen\'s Coll., Oxon, M.A., a member of the South-eastern circuit, reporter for Law Times in Queen\'s Bench division, a student of the Inner Temple 14 April, 1874 (then aged 23), called to the bar 25 April, 1877 (eldest son of William Eversley, Esq., of London); born u2060, 1851. rn> rn> 7, King\'s Bench Walk, Temple, E.C." rn> ...[in Foster\'s Men at the Bar][1]rnrnrn rnrn[1]: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Men-at-the-Bar/Eversley,_William_Pinder "Men at the Bar""}, "name": "William Pinder Eversley", "created": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "death_date": "1918", "photos": [6897255, 6897254], "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2018-07-31T15:39:07.982159"}, "latest_revision": 6, "key": "/authors/OL1003081A", "birth_date": "1851", "personal_name": "William Pinder Eversley", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 6} {"name": "Valerie Meyer", "personal_name": "Valerie Meyer", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T18:22:33.63997"}, "key": "/authors/OL1004062A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2} {"name": "Ticonius", "created": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "personal_name": "Ticonius", "birth_date": "4th cent.", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2013-02-25T09:53:08.232734"}, "latest_revision": 2, "key": "/authors/OL1004101A", "date": "4th cent", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2} {"name": "Abdul Kahar Muzakar", "created": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "death_date": "1965", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2017-03-31T12:48:41.973551"}, "latest_revision": 4, "key": "/authors/OL100450A", "birth_date": "1921", "personal_name": "Abdul Kahar Muzakar", "remote_ids": {"viaf": "11565164", "wikidata": "Q4665459"}, "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 4} {"name": "Sheshadri Narayanan", "personal_name": "Sheshadri Narayanan", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T18:36:13.030909"}, "key": "/authors/OL1005861A", "birth_date": "1936", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2} {"name": "M. W. Nuttall", "personal_name": "M. W. Nuttall", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T18:36:46.701507"}, "key": "/authors/OL1005942A", "birth_date": "1947", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2} {"name": "R.-R Renella", "personal_name": "R.-R Renella", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T18:40:50.827135"}, "key": "/authors/OL1006482A", "birth_date": "1949", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2} {"name": "Caesar A. Casanova", "personal_name": "Caesar A. Casanova", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-09-08T16:24:07.101641"}, "key": "/authors/OL100656A", "birth_date": "1948", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2} {"name": "Rodney Fitch", "personal_name": "Rodney Fitch", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T18:43:01.916355"}, "key": "/authors/OL1006767A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2} {"name": "Catherine Ingram", "links": [{"url": "http://catherineingram.com/biography.html", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Biography"}, {"url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lJK9cfXP3c", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Interview on Consciousness TV"}, {"url": "http://www.huffingtonpost.com/catherine-ingram/", "type": {"key": "/type/link"}, "title": "Blog on Huffington Post"}], "created": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "personal_name": "Catherine Ingram", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2013-04-05T06:41:53.345668"}, "latest_revision": 4, "key": "/authors/OL1006815A", "birth_date": "1952", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 4}'
Stack = []
LastJsonEndIndex = 0
PassADot = False
Count = 0
for i in range(len(my_json)):
    if PassADot:
        PassADot = False
        continue
    if my_json[i] == "{":
        Stack.append(my_json[i])
    elif my_json[i] == "}":
        Stack.pop()
        if Stack == []:
            with open("./json{}.json".format(str(Count)),"w+") as f:
                f.write(my_json[LastJsonEndIndex:i+1])
            Count += 1
            LastJsonEndIndex = i+2
            PassADot = True
    else:
        pass
```

It will generate some json file.
And you can connect it  with my firstly post.

Comment: I watch it and i come into  you in some minutes,   for real , thank you !!

Comment: @raph Actually,I know your problem is there are many jsons in one file instead of one json have the same keys.

Comment: @raph So after slice this json your problem will solve.What you should do now is 
to traversal the sliced json file.And then,you can use ``my_json.get('name')``

Comment: So for the moment i have like you said,  a lot of file json .      But i'm searching how i can put all these file in 1 file with a separate to keep the json format

Comment: @raph you needn't to put them in one file,like ``NameList = [] for i in range(num_of_jsonfile): with open("./json{}.json".format(str(i)),'r+') as f: OneJson = json.load(f) NameList.append(OneJson["name"])``,And NameList is the list of name.

Comment: ohh  did you mean that i can open all my file who have same name ( except number)  with  the loop  that you put ?       Realy thank you for all your answer,

Comment: Thank you man,   and Did I absolutely need  to  did  myjson=  .........       ???,   I can't get all my json in the file who is the big data (openlibrary5.json)  like for the begining of the post ?

Comment: @raph Can you use ``json.load()`` to load openlibrary5.json normally?This json have many json in one json file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example if use string,

```
my_json = '{"name": "Halo","action": "what?","name": "haha","action": "what?","name": "zzzz","action": "what?"}'
import json
def handle(lst):
    result = {}
    count = {}
    for key, val in lst:
        if key in count:
            count[key] = 1 + count[key]
        else:
            count[key] = 1
        if key in result:
            if count[key] > 2:
                result[key].append(val)
            else:
                result[key] = [result[key], val]
        else:
            result[key] = val
    return result
my_json = json.loads(my_json,object_pairs_hook=handle)
print(my_json['name'])
```

The result will be `['Halo', 'haha', 'zzzz']`

And if you have a json file,
Then

```
import json
def handle(lst):
    result = {}
    count = {}
    for key, val in lst:
        if key in count:
            count[key] = 1 + count[key]
        else:
            count[key] = 1
        if key in result:
            if count[key] > 2:
                result[key].append(val)
            else:
                result[key] = [result[key], val]
        else:
            result[key] = val
    return result
with open("./a.json","r") as f:
    my_json = json.load(f,object_pairs_hook=handle)
print(my_json['name'])
```

More about [object_pairs_hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#json.load)

Answer (score 1):

I think you maybe misunderstand me.
Your `openlibrary5.json` have many json in one file.

So if you directly load this file as json.
like this,

```
with open("openlibrary5.json","r") as f:
   yourJson = json.load(f)
```

will get error.

So I suggest that you could slice them firstly.

```
with open("openlibrary5.json","r") as f:
    stringJson = f.read()
```

And do what I have post to slice them **(they are string,not json)** into many (save as)json files.
After slice them,One of the sliced json file is a complete json.
So you can use `json.load()` to load them normally.

**If you really want to gather them together,after slicing them,You can open every sliced json file and put them to a  `List`(use List.append)**

You got it?

Comment: Yes thank you,  I will take your code and try do this,  thank you for all your work into me !     I come on you to show you  my advance on this project   in 1 or 2 days !

Answer (score 0):

I post a new answer because i didn't unterstand something about your code

When you said :

```
Stack = []
LastJsonEndIndex = 0
PassADot = False
Count = 0
for i in range(len(my_json)):
if PassADot:
    PassADot = False
    continue
if my_json[i] == "{":
    Stack.append(my_json[i])
elif my_json[i] == "}":
    Stack.pop()
    if Stack == []:
        with open("./json{}.json".format(str(Count)),"w+") as f:
            f.write(my_json[LastJsonEndIndex:i+1])
        Count += 1
        LastJsonEndIndex = i+2
        PassADot = True
else:
    pass
```

Here you used in your code   my_json_file=   ........   and one moment you have this :

{"bio": {"type": "/type/text", "value": "> "Eversley, William Pinder, B.C.L. Queen's Coll., Oxon, M.A., a member of the South-eastern circuit, reporter for Law Times in Queen's Bench division, a student of the Inner Temple 14 April, 1874 (then aged 23), called to the bar 25 April, 1877 (eldest son of William Eversley, Esq., of London); born u2060, 1851. rn> rn> 7, King's Bench Walk, Temple, E.C." rn> ...[in Foster's *Men at the Bar*][1]rnrnrn  rnrn[1]: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Men-at-the-Bar/Eversley,_William_Pinder "Men at the Bar""}, "name": "William Pinder Eversley", "created": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "death_date": "1918", "photos": [6897255, 6897254], "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2018-07-31T15:39:07.982159"}, "latest_revision": 6, "key": "/authors/OL1003081A", "birth_date": "1851", "personal_name": "William Pinder Eversley", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 6}

But how you did to delete this error and add  \ at right position to don't have error.

Can you explain me pls ?  You did it with  your script ? or manual ?

Comment: The purpose of why I add \ is to show your json clearly.``my_json`` is a string,So I need to add \

Comment: I want to say my English is poor,so my expression may have some mistakes.

Comment: json.loads() can convert string to dict(or json)

Comment: json.load() can convert the json file's content to dict(or json)

Comment: no problem, me too i'm not that good in english,   but you add \  per yourself so ?  not  with a script ?

Comment: Yes,just by myself,And use pycharm hot key.

Answer (score 0):

When I use your code to parse json,  it works perfectly.

But i'm just asking me how can I add \ like you did but for    10000000  lines of data.

When i take your my_json_file it works and it is split into  13files,  but  when i took my real data,  it doesn't work.

That's why i'm searching how to have something like you but i can't add per myself

Answer (score 0):

So I did a lot of thing since last time,   I have all my line in json of all my data  except for the lines :"bio",  I show you :

```
 import json,sqlite3

 ligne = []
 personal_nom = []
 tout = []

 conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
 cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute("""
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OPENLIBRARY3(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
 nom TEXT,
 personal_name TEXT
 )
 """)
 conn.commit()

 with open('openlibrary.json') as file:
 for i in range(98):
    line = file.readline()
    if "bio" in line:
        line.replace("\'", "’")
        continue
    content_json = json.loads(line)
    if not "name" in line:
       #print('NULL')
       ligne.append("NULL")
       continue
    try:
        #print(content_json['name'])
        ligne.append(content_json['name'])
    except IndexError:
        print
    if not "personal_name" in line:
        # print('NULL')
        personal_nom.append("NULL")
        continue
    try:
        # print(content_json['name'])
        personal_nom.append(content_json['personal_name'])
    except IndexError:
        print


  #print(ligne)
  #print(personal_nom)


  #for i in ligne:



  new_list=[]
  #for y in range(0,len(ligne)):
  #    list.append(("("+ligne[(y)]+")"))

  #for element in ligne:
  #    new_list.append(tuple(element))

 #print(new_list)

 resultat = []
 for name in zip(ligne):
   resultat.append((name))
 #print(resultat)


 print(tout)


 cur.executemany("""
 INSERT INTO OPENLIBRARY3(nom) VALUES(?)""", resultat)
 #cur.executemany("""
 #INSERT INTO OPENLIBRARY3(personal_name) VALUES(?)""", personal_nom)

 valeur = []

req = "select * from OPENLIBRARY3"
result = cur.execute(req)
print(type(result))
for row in result:
   valeur.append(row[1])

print(valeur)
#for j in range(len(ligne)):
#    content = ligne[j]
#    content_json = json.loads(content)
#    print(content_json['name'])
```

So i got this

[('violette', '2018-05-23'), ('violete', '2018-05-23'), ('Alice au pays des merveilles', '2017-12-23'), ('Alice aux pays des merveilles', '2017-12-23'), ('La plaete des singes ', '2015-02-1'), ('La planete des singes 2', '2016-03-16'), ('Titanic', '2012-02-02'), ('Kin
g Kong', '2004-04-12'), ('Kink Konk', '2005-09-25')]

the problem is that i can't recover this line because she has always a lot of problem :

{"bio": {"type": "/type/text", "value": "> "Eversley, William Pinder, B.C.L. Queen's Coll., Oxon, M.A., a member of the South-eastern circuit, reporter for Law Times in Queen's Bench division, a student of the Inner Temple 14 April, 1874 (then aged 23), called to the bar 25 April, 1877 (eldest son of William Eversley, Esq., of London); born u2060, 1851. rn> rn> 7, King's Bench Walk, Temple, E.C." rn> ...[in Foster's *Men at the Bar*][1]rnrnrn  rnrn[1]: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Men-at-the-Bar/Eversley,_William_Pinder "Men at the Bar""}, "name": "William Pinder Eversley", "created": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "death_date": "1918", "photos": [6897255, 6897254], "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2018-07-31T15:39:07.982159"}, "latest_revision": 6, "key": "/authors/OL1003081A", "birth_date": "1851", "personal_name": "William Pinder Eversley", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 6}

When I put this line in python to recover in with my code,  it put a error, so i need don't take this and all work,   I tried  something in Batch, i tried to remplace every   '  in bio  per `  but  it puts an other problem and other problem,  I have no idea how i can correct this, i don't know if it's possible ...

Thanks to listen me and sorry again,  i come here late because i'm tired and i tried too much.

Thanks again !

If i spoke bad about my problem, ask question and i will clarify !